# OpenLayers - How do I project a custom tile layer to a view of [-200,-200,200, 200]?

Tags: openlayers

I'm trying to use openlayers to visualize data in a fictitious map. I have 5 zoom levels of tiles and I can visualize this layer well.  The extents that works for this layer is [-4096, -4096, 4096, 4096].

I have another data stream of dynamic features that can come and go. My problem is with combining the tile layer with my dynamic feature layer. The dynamic data is in a coordinate system of [-200, -200, 200, 200].

I want both of these layers to cover the same space.   ie: [-200, -200, 200, 200] is just a scaled down version of [-4096, -4096, 4096, 4096].

What combinations of view (extent, projection) and source (extent, projection, options) do I need to allow both of these layers work together? Or is this the only solution to scale the dynamic coordinates to the tile's projection?

Thanks

Comment: So how’s this a programming question? Maybe try at https://gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: I guess i was thinking it's a programming question because openlayers is a javascript mapping api.   The solution i'm hoping for will help me utilize that api to achieve my desired goal.